# Could you please help me to write a formula Salesforce

Tags: formula

Coud you please help?

I need convert this SQL code to Salesforce Formula

left(Price_Lookup_Id, case when charindex(':', Price_Lookup_Id) = 0 then len(Price_Lookup_Id) else charindex(':', Price_Lookup_Id)-1 end

Do you have any idea how to rewrite to formulas sytnax?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) is a good place to start learning these core skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help.

```
LEFT(Price_Lookup_Id, IF(FIND(":", Price_Lookup_Id, 1) = 0, LEN(Price_Lookup_Id), FIND(":", Price_Lookup_Id, 1) - 1))
```

If you face anything let me know.

Comment: Thank You bro! It is working!